# UiTabController app setup

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am on the beginning stages of my project. It is a UITabbedApplication with three tabs. The tab at [0] position is the "Location picker", the [1] tab is the "view profiles" from the location picked in the Location picker view. Depending on the location that is first chosen I want the view profiles tab to show profiles from that specific location. Would I be able to do this with container views or is the way I want this set up not going to work? Any advice would be helpful.

```
 //tab [0] choose location
 class ChooseLocationVC: UIViewController {
@IBAction func chooseAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if pageControl.currentPage == 0{

        print("LA")
    }
    else if pageControl.currentPage == 1{

        print("SF")
    }else if pageControl.currentPage == 2{

        print("NY")
    }else if pageControl.currentPage == 3{

        print("Miami")
    }else if pageControl.currentPage == 4{

        print("LasVegas")
    }else if pageControl.currentPage == 5{

        print("Chicago")
    }

}
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var thisWidth:CGFloat = 0

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "LA"),UIImage(named: "SF"), UIImage(named: "NY"), UIImage(named: "Miami"), UIImage(named: "LasVegas"), UIImage(named: "Chicago")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setLabels()
   // thisWidth = CGFloat(self.frame.width)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.locationImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(scrollView.frame.width)
    setLabels()
    print(pageControl.currentPage)
}

}
```

Comment: You need to show output at tab[1] after a Input from Tab[0] Right, Make use of struct to store value inputted in tab[0] and when you had received input and you navigate to tab[1] get struct value and show result

Comment: is this Done or still pending ?

Answer (score 0):

My StoryBoard :

```
A tab Bar Controller - > 

  -> VC2 tab[0]
  -> VC3 tab[1]
```

[image]

My Struct Class that Will take data from VC2 To VC3

```
struct Global
{
    static var Location : String!
}
```

My VC2 Class :

```
import UIKit

class VC2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textTF: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        print("Called of vC2")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func saveValue(_ sender: Any)
    {
        Global.Location = self.textTF.text
    }

}
```

My VC3 Class:

```
import UIKit
class VC3: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultTf: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("Called of vC3")
        if Global.Location != ""
        {
            self.resultTf.text = Global.Location
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: doing this, would I be able to have 5-6 different viewControllers for one tab? Or would it be ideal to have one view controller and depending on which location was picked to display different information?

Comment: you can have as much tabs you want struct is just used here to access The value in any class , Create multiple static var variable under struct and store as many variables you want for as many as controller , Struct do not give any Limitation it just act as a singleton class

Comment: I just used 2 Vc in tab here you can use as many VC you want in one Tab

Comment: see the thing is..I want may second tab to display different information depending on which location is chosen from my first tab.

Comment: yes you can do that , Its just depend on your code , I had just showed you an example how to manage VC3 Output from VC1 Input

Comment: if you face any issue Regarding this feel free to ask , I will let you know the solution for that, But using struct do not give any Limitation of Adding VC in Tab, Struct is used just to store some Variable thats it