# swift; xcode 9.2 - Passing arguments over TabBar & navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

In my storyboard I got:

UIView -> UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UITableView

Now I want to pass an object from UIView into UITableview. I do get the object to the TabBarController from the prepare for segue func, but from there I kind of get lost.

How to identify what segue you have on the itemlist from the TabBarController?

Could somebody give some example code for the UITabBar and Navigation controller to pass the data?

Comment: Don't pass anything.  Create an object that serves as an interface to your data model.  Tell it how to modify data when that's needed and then ask it for the current data when you want to display information.

Comment: I need a bit more explanation I think. I am a bit of a n00b :) and do not understand completely how to achieve what you are suggesting (although I do understand the basic principle what you are suggesting).

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/48575989/6080920 I shared using structs in this case

Answer (score 0):

Phillip  is right.

You can do it as following:

```
class Model {
    static let shared = Model()

    var data: String // or anything else
}
```

in UIView:

```
Model.shared.data = "some data"
```

in UITableView

```
let data = Model.shared.data
//do smth with data...
```

Comment: Getting clearer, thank you. I will give it a try!
Class Model is separate file I guess which should be imported in the UIView and UITableview I guesss?

Comment: If you are using Objective C then yes. With Swift you don't need to import files that are inside of the same project.

Comment: But Model is surely in a separate file.

Comment: ok, tx. Got an error on the Model.shared.data ..... Instance member 'shared' cannot be used on type Model .... :(

Answer (score 0):

Anton is suggesting the Singleton pattern. It is important to understand what it is when you decide to use it has both its benefits and potential pitfalls. https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/ is a place to start reading up.

There are ways to just pass an object from one view to the other and that is useful knowledge to know. Both TabBarVC's and NavigationVC's have their `viewControllers` property which allows you to access an array of their child vc's. You can use this to pass information to specific child vc's. Depending on your needs this may be more appropriate than creating a singleton.

For example:

```
let childVC = tabBarVC.viewControllers[0] as! MyCustomVCClass
childVC.inheretedObject = objectIWantToSend
```

This would pass an object to the vc that ocupies the first tab of a tab bar vc.

Comment: Tx as well, clear what you mean with the pitfalls (was good read) and thank you for pointing out the TabBar solution, clear as well.

Comment: Glad to help, if you used one of our answers and feel it was correct, don't forget to mark it as such.